# Blender frozen, Is there anything I can do?

Tags: rendering

After 63h of rendering I hit f3 to save as png and blender froze, It's been frozen for 12h already.
Is there anything I can do so I don't have to render again?
Maybe there is a way to recover last session with atleast part of the render already rendered?

Comment: Did the render got saved in blenders temp folder ?

Comment: I didn't see any files there...

Comment: If you want I can render it on a farm, should be done in 2~3 hours then.